# Crystal report page changing

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

How can we handle page changing in crystal report if report consist more than one page.

Comment: What do you mean "handle page changing"?

Comment: Will the report automatically load the the content of the next page without writing any code or we have to bind the data on page change event.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the inbuilt crystal reports viewer then it will be handled automatically by the control itself. Also you have other options provided by crystal report to export it to various formats like pdf, txt etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use Special Field is Page Number and than input it in your report Haeder or footer that you need to show.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports:
1.Go to Report > Section Expert>
2.Highlight the Group Footer section for the group that needs to have the page break>
3.Mark the New Page After checkbox>
4.Click OK
Refresh the report
It's work